# How mail with attachment of PDF report generated through cron. Odoo 14

Tags: xml, cron, odoo, qweb

I want to send mail with attachment of PDF report generated through cron.
the model : "stock.warehouse.orderpoint".

I want to send mail with report PDF containing the information of model "stock.warehouse.orderpoint", when trying this code , I got many mail with each report of stock orderpoint in a mail. But I want one mail with one report.

//the cron :

```
  <record id="ir_cron_auto_send_mail_quantity_notifier" model="ir.cron">
    <field name="name">Quantity Notifier</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="stock.model_stock_warehouse_orderpoint"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
       <field name="code">
        for stock in env['stock.warehouse.orderpoint'].search([]):
            try:
                stock.send_reminder_mail()
                env.cr.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                pass
          </field>
    <field name="active" eval="True"/>
    <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
    <field name='interval_number'>1</field>
    <field name='interval_type'>days</field>
    <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

//mail function:

class StockWarehouseOrderpoint(models.Model):
_inherit = "stock.warehouse.orderpoint"

```
def send_reminder_mail(self, force_send=True):
    template_id = self.env.ref("my_module.email_template_quantity_reminder")
    if template_id:
            template_id.send_mail(self.id, force_send=force_send, email_values={"email_to": "test@gmail.com"},)

    return True
```

//report template:

```
<template id="report_quantity_notifier">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <div class="page">
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <strong>Article</strong>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <strong>Emplacement</strong>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <strong>Qty Alert</strong>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <strong>Qty disponible</strong>
                            </th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="font-size:20px"  t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                            <td>
                                <span t-field="doc.product_id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span t-field="doc.location_id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span t-field="doc.product_min_qty"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span t-field="doc.qty_on_hand"/>
                            </td>
                          
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>

    <record id="quantity_report" model="ir.actions.report">
        <field name="name">Quantity</field>
        <field name="model">stock.warehouse.orderpoint</field>
        <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
        <field name="report_name">my_module.report_quantity_notifier</field>
        <field name="report_file">my_module.report_quantity_notifier</field>
        <field name="binding_model_id" ref="stock.model_stock_warehouse_orderpoint"/>
        <field name="binding_type">report</field>
    </record>
```

How to do it , any help please? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to remove the for loop and just call `send_reminder_mail()` on your search result?